# Magical Records - How to map relationships using key path?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an `NSManagedObjectModel` subclass, named **AOStartup**. I am receiving XML that has nested objects within it, which I call **AOReportType**. On my **AOStartup** object, I have a one-to-many relationship called **reportTypes** that has a destination of **AOReportType** and an inverse relationship set too.

I am parsing the XML to an `NSDictionary` (which creates an inner array of the **AOReportType** data content) and then use the following method to map it to the **AOStartup** object:

```
[startup importValuesForKeysWithObject:dictionary];
```

All of the attributes map correctly. However, the relationship isn't mapping right.

Here's the relevant `NSDictionary` code (copied and pasted from console log):

```
reportTypes = {        
    reportType = (
        {
            "_id" = 727;
            backgroundColor = FFFFFF;
            mayCreate = false;
            name = "Animal Codes";
            navBarColor = 350000;
            referenced = false;
            reportName = Code;
            reportVersion = 0;
        },

        {
            "_id" = 718;
            backgroundColor = FFFFFF;
            mayCreate = false;
            name = "Business License Codes";
            navBarColor = 350000;
            referenced = false;
            reportName = Code;
            reportVersion = 0;
        },
```

Here's a screen shot of the **reportTypes** relationship and its user info on **AOStartup** in the model object builder:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAWfi.png

Note also, that I have set the `mappedKeyName` key as `"reportTypes.reportType"` on the user info on the **reportTypes** relationship.

Why aren't the nested objects mapping correctly?

Comment: Ummm...  What is the question?

Comment: The question was "why aren't relationships mapping automatically given the dictionary above?" I've figured it out though (it's a bug in Magical Import). See answer below.

Comment: Try to succinctly ask the question at the start of your question box, then go into detail afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Magical Records / Magical Import (master branch as of September 7, 2012).

Currently, magical records **does** support mapping attributes by KVC paths. However, it does **not** support mapping relationships by KVC paths.

I've fixed this issue in my local branch, and I'm going to put in a pull request to merge it into master.

FYI--

The issue is with **NSManagedObject+MagicalDataImport.m** around line 129. This line is wrong:

```
        id relatedObjectData = [relationshipData valueForKey:lookupKey];
```

It should actually be:

```
        id relatedObjectData = [relationshipData valueForKeyPath:lookupKey];
```

Comment: FYI: for new users, who come to this page like me:
It's not actual.
If you're using new version - don't worry about that.
This bug fixed already.